# Ошибка шрифтов TinyMCE

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'arial black', 'avant garde';">mb kbkbl
> ')' at line 1

При попытку ввести текст шрифтом ArialBlack и другие, при записи в БД вылезает такая вот ошибка. Все остальное нормально работает. Что делать?

Answer (score 1):

У вас для двухсловных шрифтов используются какие-либо кавычки.
Попробуйте поменять их или заэкранировать.

Вообще, вы ж в БД вставляете своим кодом? 
Есть мега функция РНР - mysql_real_escape_string - используйте её, перед тем как совать переменную в скрипт вставки

Напр:

```
 @mysql_query("insert into texts (val) values('".@mysql_real_escape_string($mytext)."');";
```

Comment: она теперь добавляет пустую запись

Comment: 1. Агрументом функции нужно засовывать ту переменную или строку, которя нужна, а результат присоеденять к запросу.
2. Вызов функции должен идти после подключения к БД.
3. Уберите символ @ - и почитайте сообщение об ошибке, которая происходит.
4. http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php